# Custom reusable component using apostrophe with react

Tags: reactjs, content-management-system, apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

I am a new in using apostrophe. I read that apostrophe is build on node.js as a backend, express and nunjucks template 
my questions is can I create my custom reusable component using react on apostrophe without using headless CMS?

or to be able to use react with apostrophe it must be with Rest API (headless CMS)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi Menna, Apostrophe does not do anything that would prevent you from using React together with it. Have you given it a try? Did you encounter problems? Specifics would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Tom, I think react can be with apostrophe as a headless CMS when using apostrophe as backend and calling react project through APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use React with Apostrophe, even if you are not using `apostrophe-headless`. React does not insist on "owning" the entire page, and neither does Apostrophe.

This can be as simple as adding some `script` tags to your `outerLayout.html` or an individual page template, overriding the `extraHead` nunjucks block to load them. You may want to bring babel into your project to allow the use of JSX however.

See the [official React documentation on using it in existing websites](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html).